# std::move() as performance bottleneck?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, move-semantics

I have a custom ringbuffer implementation which uses a normal array allocated via `new []`, and then uses `std::move` to move elements into the array. Here is the implementation of my `push()` method:

```
void push(value_type&& value)
{
    _content[_end] = std::move(value); // 9.2% of execution is spend here
    increment(); // 0.6% here
}
```

The objects I'm moving into the array are basically just a pointer and a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
struct Task
{
    Task()
    {}

    Function function;
    Batch *batch;
};
```

And `Function` looks like this:

```
class Function
{
public:
    template<typename F>
    Function(F&& f) :
        _implementation(new ImplementationType<F>(std::move(f)))
    {}

    void operator() () { _implementation->Call(); }

    Function() = default;
    Function(Function&& other) :
        _implementation(std::move(other._implementation))
    {}

    Function& operator=(Function&& other)
    {
        _implementation = std::move(other._implementation);
        return *this;
    }

    Function(const Function&) = delete;
    Function(Function&) = delete;
    Function& operator= (const Function&) = delete;

private:
    struct Base
    {
        virtual void Call() = 0;
        virtual ~Base() {}
    };

    template<typename F>
    struct ImplementationType : Base
    {
        ImplementationType(F&& f) :
            function(std::move(f))
        {}

        void Call()
        {
            function();
        }

        F function;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Base> _implementation;
};
```

I call the ringbuffers `push()` method repeatedly in a loop to fill the buffer up with tasks, there is no other computation happening there. I would expect the `std::move()` to have very little overhead, and definitely not eat up the biggest chunk of my computation time. Can anyone point me into the right direction of what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: How did you ascertain this? `std::move` calls should not survive the optimiser of any compiler worth its salt.

Comment: I attached `Instruments` to the program and captured about two minutes runtime. It marks the line where I move the data into the array with taking 9.2% of the execution time (as marked in the comments). Compiled with `-Os` and no debug stuff or runtime assertions left using the latest Clang that ships with Xcode 5.

Comment: It's not `std::move`. It's the move constructor of your objects.  I'm not sure what you expect here: if you do nothing but put stuff in the buffer, putting stuff in the buffer (i.e. moving it in) will be the most common activity.

Comment: Well, that's the thing, the program is doing much much more, which I would expect to take up much more time. The moving stuff into the buffer part is just a tiny tiny fraction of what the program is doing, hence my surprise about its performance impact.

Comment: `std::move` is just a compile time cast that generates no runtime code at all. More precisely, `std::move(value)` is equivalent to `static_cast<value_type&&>(value)`. It doesn't cost anything at runtime.

Comment: If `_content[_end]` isn't empty, then assigning the unique pointer will delete the old object. Perhaps that's what's taking the time?

Comment: @CassioNeri Fine, it's not the `std::move` but the move constructor then (which is also just a `std::move`), but why is it so slow then?! Seriously, this code is running in a 3d game engine which does a thousand different things including physics updates... Even if it was horribly implemented, I would not expect it to take that much time.

Comment: @MikeSeymour That does sound plausible! I totally forgot about that, but you are right, I just keep overwriting the array all the time!

Comment: @MikeSeymour Nail -> Head. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @JustSid I don't know but it's definitely not `std::move`. We don't have enough information here. For instance, if `_content` is of type `std::map<K, V>` then its `operator []` could be the culprit. Mike Seymour's guess is also good one but as much as mine it's only a guess. Even if we had the whole code only the profiler can give you the right answer.

Comment: @CassioNeri Sorry I didn't make that clear enough, but `_content` is a normal array allocated via `new []`. And yeah, I did attach a profiler, and I was at a total loss about the results (because it did point to the `std::move()`), hence my question here. Mike Seymour was right though.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Your guess (that's the move constructor) is a good one but (I'm almost sure that) you'll agree with me that we don't have enough information here. What if `_content` is a `std::map<K, V>`?

Comment: @JustSid Fair enough. I'm glad Mike Seymour was right. ;-)

Comment: It would be nice if the question title did not contain a jumped-to conclusion :P Not sure what else you'd say there now, though, other than "help me realise what I'm not considering plz"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wasn't judging with my title, I was asking wether it was a performance bottleneck (see the question mark at the end)

Comment: Yeah, I know. But we now know that the title is unrelated to the given problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::move` itself does nothing at runtime; it just casts its argument into an *rvalue* suitable for passing to the move-assignment operator. It's the assignment that will be taking time.

If `_content[_end]` isn't empty, then reassigning the unique pointer will delete the old object. Perhaps that's what's taking the time?