# How to get the move constructor calling deliberately

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

Consider following code:

```
class Base {
public:
    int bi;
    Base() : bi(100)    {std::cout << "\nBase default constructor ...";}
    Base(int i) : bi(i) {std::cout << "\nBase int constructor: "<< bi;}
    Base(const Base& b) {std::cout << "\nBase copy constructor";}
    Base(Base&& b)      {std::cout << "\nBase move constructor";}
};

Base getBase() {
    cout << "\nIn getBase()";
    return Base();  
}
int main() {
    Base b2(getBase());  
    Base b3 = Base(2);   
    Base b4 = getBase(); 
}
```

In spite of rvalues being given, none of the above constructions in main are calling the move constructor. Is there a way to ensure that user defined move constructor is called?

Here is what I am getting:

```
In getBase()    
Base default constructor ...
Base int constructor: 2
In getBase()
Base default constructor ...
Base destructor: 100
Base destructor: 2
Base destructor: 100
```

Comment: before someone else give good answer, check this out http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

Comment: calling the move constructor is simply optimized away. "Copy elision" is your friend!

Comment: Looks like `getBase()` is being inlined - try building that in its own translation unit and then linking.

Comment: `@TobySpeight` That is giving a Segmentation fault!

Comment: `@Klaus` This was my point; how I can I force the call to move constructor? std::move() is one way.

Comment: @DKR you mean you wanted to know ways other than `std::move()`?

Comment: `@MarsonMao` you already mentioned that in first comment. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19500502) tells that move will generate rvalue. The same I intended in my code but that got optimized away. Does it mean that the calls in my code are not resulting in rvalue?

Comment: @DKR I managed to understand what you were thinking. The question was marked as duplicate so that I can only answer here. Try the code below and you can see the move constructor being called. `Base1 operator + (const Base1& other)
    {
        int me = bi;
        int it = other.bi;
        Base1 next(me + it);
        return next;
    }`. Then make an object like `Base1 b6 = b1 + b2;`. I guess the point is to force a temporary object so that return value optimization has no chance to interfere .

Comment: `@MarsonMao` Your code also resulting into RVO. Here is the output: `Base default constructor ...
Base default constructor ...
In operator+
Base int constructor: 200
`

Comment: `@MarsonMao` can you do something now to un-mark it as duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::move()` method:

```
Base b4 = std::move(getBase());
```

This ensures that move constructor is called, but in this line it prevents copy-elision to optimalize copy constructor out of there. There is no need to call any constructor, so this is more example how to not use `std::move()`.

Comment: `getBase()` is already a prvalue, and you prevent copy-elision to happen

Comment: @Ormei, instead of referring to the comments, perhaps you could explain this directly in the answer?

Comment: `@PiotrSkotnicki` if `getBase()` is already a prvalue than why the move constructor is not being called?

Comment: When you write `Base b4 = getBase();`, copy-elision optimalizes the code to construct `Base` object right on place of `b4`, so there is no copy or move constructors called at all.

Comment: `@Ormei` can you suggest any other way also to deliberately call move constructor?

Comment: `std::move` is pretty much all you need to call move constructor, only it should be called in different context. Consider `Base b4` has lots of data allocated in some containers inside and you want to push it into vector, `vector <Base> vb; ... vb.push_back(std::move(b4));`. This can save a lot of time and space. PS: If you are pushing rvalue, vector calls automaticaly move constructor.